# I have raw CSV data. How can I change into numbers with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

This is an example of my data. Is from the Stack Overflow Developers survey, but this is how they have the data. My goal is to create some charts using d3.js

```
Australia,30-34,Male
Canada,25-29,Male
Canada,30-34,Male
Denmark,30-34,Male
Germany,25-29,Male
```

etc..

How Can Use d3.js to say "Every time you found a male count it and also remember the country as the primary key".

Comment: Or maybe how Can I calculate the total of each answer to the question how many male developers are in this dataset with d3

Comment: on the high-level: split, filter, then map. if you want details, show us a sample output.

Comment: You can achieve this and more read d3 nest for grouping http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/ this will help

Comment: Thank you very much, I nested my data and after that it was easy to manipulate and create totals of each one of them.